# On-page email header missing in Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-headers

When I send emails from my email-server to Gmail it doesn't show the:

```
First Last <email@domain1.com>
```

It only shows:

```
First Last
```

It shows the email if I hover over it, but not on the page.

For some strange reason, it will show the email header on-page if I send from a user that doesn't have a mailbox setup. i.e. sending from contact@domain1.com but there is no associated mailbox - then it shows:

```
First Last <contact@domain1.com>
```

For an some even stranger reason, it will show the email header on-page from a mailbox that exists if I include an '@' symbol in the sender name. i.e. First Las@t will show:

```
First Las@t <email@domain1.com>
```

but First Last will only show:

```
First Last
```

Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: Is `First Last <email@domain1.com>` in the contacts of the Gmail recipient account?